# Project Euler #19 in Java (off by 1)

Tags: java, calendar

You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some research for yourself.

1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
Thirty days has September,
April, June and November.
All the rest have thirty-one,
Saving February alone,
Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
And on leap years, twenty-nine.
A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.
How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

I have been getting 172 and the answer is 171. I am not sure what might be the problem, I have tried everything and I keep getting 172. Thanks for your help.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int year=1901;
    boolean isLeapYear=false;
    int totalSundays=0;
    int currentDay=1;//Starts on a Monday
    while(year<=2000){
        isLeapYear=false;
        if((year%4)==0){
            if((year%100)==0 && (year%400)==0){
                isLeapYear=true;
            } else if((year%100)==0 && (year%400)!=0){
                isLeapYear=false;
            } else {
                isLeapYear=true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The Year Is: "+year);
        System.out.println("*******************************");
        for(int month=1;month<=12;month++){
            System.out.println("The Month is: "+month+" currentDay is :  "+currentDay);
            if(currentDay==7){
                totalSundays++;
            }
            if(month==1 || month==3 || month==5 || month==7 || month==8 || month==10 || month==12){
            //January,March,May,July,August,October,December
                currentDay+=3;
            } else if(month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11){ 
            //April,June,September,November
                currentDay+=2;              
            } else if(month==2 && isLeapYear){
            //February has 29 days in a Leap Year
                currentDay+=1;
            } 

            if(currentDay>7){
                currentDay=currentDay-7;
            }
            System.out.println("Updated Current Day Is :  "+currentDay);
        }
        System.out.println("*******************************");
        year++;
    }
    System.out.println("The total number of Sundays that fell in the first of the month is: "+totalSundays);
}
```

Comment: FYI, this would be a lot easier for you/us to follow and maintain if you eliminated the magic numbers and used `final int`s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're starting on the wrong day. Jan 1, 1901 is actually a Tuesday (so `currentDay = 2`.) Making that change results in 171: http://ideone.com/mh4MJ

Comment: Thanks for the help, yeah it in fact starts on a Tuesday, given that Jan 1, 1900 is a Monday and there are 365 days in the year 1900 so Jan 1, 1901 should be Tuesday.

Comment: Its really interesting how many people instinctually assumed that Jan 1, 1901 is a Monday rather than checking.

Answer (score 0):

without using calendar it would be:

```
static int getDays(int month, int year){
    switch (month){
    case 4:case 6: case 9: case 11:
        return 30;
    case 2:
        return (isLeapYear(year))?29:28;
    }
    return 31;
}

static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
    boolean leap = false;
    if(year%4==0){
        if(year%100==0){
            leap = (year%400==0)?true:false;
        }
        else{
            leap = true;
        }
    }
    return leap;
}

static int q19(){
    int year = 1901;
    // Sun:1 Mon: 2 ...
    int firstDay = 3; // 1 Jan 1901 was Tuesday 
    int sundays = 0;
    for(int i=year;i<2001;i++){
        int days_In_Month = getDays(1,i);
        int dif = days_In_Month%7;
        if(i!=year)
            firstDay = (dif+firstDay)%7;
        if(firstDay == 1) sundays++;
        for(int m = 2;m<=12;m++){
            firstDay = (dif+firstDay)%7;
            if(firstDay == 1) sundays++;
            days_In_Month = getDays(m,i);
            dif = days_In_Month%7;
        }
    }
    return sundays;
}
```